# Place for Test-projects in projects structure

Tags: .net, projects-and-solutions

Below you can see my current project structure. But I am not fully happy with it. The main problem is that I don't know where to put Test projects.

According to the title, it would be logically to put YML.Tests inside YML folder. But in this case I will mix YML project structure and YML.Tests project folder (it is not critical but I don't like it).

Another way is to rename YML.Tests to YMLTests and then there will be less reasons to put YMLTests inside YML. But then I will want to combine YML and YMLTests into one folder. And I have to idea how to name it. YML? Then YML project will be inside one more YML folder.

Hm... Any ideas how to make it better?

[image]

Comment: Why are YML and YML.Tests in a "Feed" folder to start with?

Comment: Because YML is a feed standard. So there will be different feeds support implementations in Feeds folder

Comment: @Idsa: But they're all different projects, right? I tend to keep all my projects at the top level within the solution. It's also not clear why you aren't happy with the structure as it stands.

Comment: I don't like to have some project and its test project on the same level of hierarchy. Moreover sometimes I have two test projects for one module: one more test project for long-running tests.

Comment: @Idsa: *Why* don't you like that? They're both projects, so they're peers of each other in that respect. The way you've currently got it set up is how I'd do it. If you want a separate project for longrunning tests (instead of just using categories etc) you can just set up a third project.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Hm... May be you are right and current implementation is good enough. But test project has no value without implementation project so may be it would be right to combine them into one folder some way...

Comment: @ldsa: You will get more visibility for your question if you add a language tag.

Comment: @Rick Sladkey: I don't think this question is language-specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The organizational structure of the projects in your solution should be designed to maximize your productivity when working in the solution.  Some of the factors that affect your productivity are project size, logical grouping, and navigational ease.

In this case I think you are wrestling with two different competing organizational concepts:

- organization by software product function (feeds, extractors, etc.)
- organization by software development function (implementation, test, etc.)

As a result, you could create a separate test tree that doesn't "pollute" your implementation tree but doing so might create a big problem for navigational ease if you constantly switch between implementation and test for the same feature area.

In the end, any organizational structure has to make some compromises, but given that you appear to be serious about test-driven development, I think the organization you've proposed is pretty good.  It's commonly used, and while it has its flaws, it is workable and productive for daily use development.